# ¿Por qué al llamar una función de la clase base se llama a la misma función?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estaba intentando lo siguiente en Python pero produce un error de máxima recursión superada:

```
class Integer(int):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{type(self)} {self}"
```

Entonces intenté llamar a la función de la clase base (`int`) para que no suceda. Pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error ya que aparentemente se está llamando a la misma función y no la definida en la clase base:

```
class Integer(int):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        s = super().__str__()
        return f"{type(self)} {s}"
```

El resultado esperado es:

```
repr(Integer(10)) // "(Integer) 10"
```

¿Cómo podría llamar a la función de la clase base visto que `super()` no funciona? Sino, de qué manera podría obtener el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola Maestro, podrías agregar la clase base?. mientras podrías probar con **return f"{ type( self.valor )} {self.valor}"** reemplaza **valor** por el atributo correspondiente.

Comment: @Marce la clase base es `int` y forma parte de los tipos básicos de python,

Comment: Siempre diciendo pavadas yo... gracias ídolo por desasnarme!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada objeto en Python del tipo int tiene implementado el `__repr__`.

Lo que este código está haciendo es reemplazando la implementación estándar y causando la recursión infinita, y esa es la causa del desbordamiento de recursión máxima.

Está creando una nueva implementación para `__repr__` sobrescribiendo la implementación estándar.

Lo que debería hacer es convertir Integer a int o llamar a la función [**object.**repr**()**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__repr__#object.__repr__) que invoca **explícitamente** la implementación estándar de la clase `object`.

```
class Integer(int):
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return object.__repr__(self)  # o int.__repr__()

print(repr(Integer(10)))
```

Comment: Probé con `super().__repr__()` y sí lo soluciona, es parecido a lo que mencionas.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Entiendo la preocupación de la comunidad por no permitir el uso de inteligencia artificial y respeto las reglas, soy programador desde hace 20 años y conozco bien los lenguajes de programación.